# My ListView's Adapter won't update

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, inotifypropertychanged

My listView consists of rows which any row has a title and an imageView (Download Icon) and a progress bar , when user click on the download image , it starts downloads the file from another java file called download task , when download finishes , i want to update the listView with notifyDataSetChannged , but haven't been able to do that , Can you help me please ?

It's part of my DownloadTask.java :

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    mInfo.setDownloadState(DownloadState.COMPLETE);
      ProgressBar progressBar = mInfo.getProgressBar();
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      mInfo.setProgressBar(progressBar);

      downloadInfoArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: onPostExecute you need to set data which you got to the collection which was used in adapter then call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I haven't add anything to my list , I just want to change the downlaod icon to play icon , when I click on the play icon the music will start playing , it's my problem that I won't decide to add anything to my list

Comment: then what is requirement to update listview

Comment: if you want to just change icon no need to notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: No , in the Activity if the icon is Download , when clicked it start downloding and when its the play icon after clicking it starts playing the music , so after download finishes i want to refresh the listview to get it know that the music is downloaded and the icon play comes visible instead of download icon and ...

Comment: for this you need to maintain a flag like isdownload for this there are many ways . you can maintain list of songs which are download locally and in adapter when set image to view check that the sound is downloaded or not.

Comment: thanks sir , then how can I notify the listview after downloading ?

Comment: Use a callback function as one of the parameters of your asynctask. Or an interface. You could call them in onPostExecute. But the simplest would be to make the task an inner class of the activity where you use it. In this way the task class has direct access to the listview and the data for the adapter.

Comment: @greenapps tank you very much , if I do so , then if don't add any item to my listview , notifyDataSetChanged will work ?

Comment: `if I do so ,`. How would you do? I named three posibilities. But of course it will always work.

Comment: Thank you , problem solved ! :)